# How do x-compile and install X11 on ARM?

Tags: x11, arm, cross-compilation

I have FriendlyARM mini210s with bare `linux 3.0.8 armv7l`. I'd like to install `X11` (X-Window System) on top of it.

How do I proceed?

Is there any ready to use package (tarball to extract onto my `rootfs`)? or will I have to x-compile and install it?

Any pointers or tips a most welcome.